# Does Ruby have any construct similar to Clojure's pmap for parallel processing?

Tags: ruby, clojure

I'm trying to decide whether to implement an application in Ruby or Clojure. Two of the requirements involve parallel processing:

1. The app must make parallel calls to fetch XML feeds and other types of data over the internet. Many such calls are made, and serializing the calls is inefficient.
2. The responses to those calls ought ideally to be processed in parallel. Processing mainly means transforming raw XML down to a much smaller piece of structured data (a Ruby hash or Clojure map) and inserting that into a MySQL database or CouchDB database.

I know Ruby a lot better than Clojure but if this is the right sort of project for Clojure I am all for using it.

Clojure's `pmap` function seems ideal for these two requirements. I'm wondering if some Ruby library or feature had a similarly clean and easy way of doing parallel processing tasks like the above.

Comment: Also, does anyone know if pmap prevents too many threads from spawning and running at once?

Comment: @dan pmap has some kind of rate control that is "semi-lazy in that the
  parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption, but doesn't
  realize the entire result unless required" ([clojure docs](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/pmap))

Comment: OK that is a little vague but useful

Comment: @dan: from the source code, I see it runs a maximum of `(+ 2 (.. Runtime getRuntime availableProcessors))` threads at once, and only computes more when you need them. (I don't fully understand the internals, because I don't understand the language in general.)

Comment: You're aware that MRI and YARV (the "default" ruby implementations) don't use more than one processor at a time, right?

Comment: @Andrew: MRI uses green threads and uses only one processor at a time. YARV uses Posix threads but has a global interpreter lock that eliminates (almost?) all concurrency. However, threads work great in both interpreters when the goal is to do something else while waiting for blocking I/O, as is the case here. (I've done it before.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple little example of one way to do this. Note that there's nothing limiting the number of threads it creates at once, so you might want to create some sort of thread pool if you're running lots of threads.

```
[1,2,3].map{|x| Thread.start{x+1}}.map{|t| t.join.value}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the `pmap` function reusable is similarly simple:

```
module Enumerable
  def pmap
    map {|x| Thread.start {yield x}}.map {|t| t.join.value}
  end
end
```

But, of course, using a proper thread pool / executor would probably be a good idea. Here’s [an example](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/simple+concurrency+ruby).

Comment: Note that the eigenclass thread pool doesn't have any easy way to get the thread's return value.

Comment: @tokland: `*args` will only ever contain one item anyway.

Comment: @Ken. Why the block should have only one argument?

Comment: @tokland, `map` passes one element at a time to the block. Why would you expect there to be more than one argument?

Comment: @Ken: I was thinking in something like this: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]].pmap { |x, y| x + y } # => [3, 5, 9]. But apparently yield([1,2]) is expanded in the block arguments |x, y|, which is suprising for me, I would expect the complete pair in x.

Comment: @tokland: That's a topic for another place.

Comment: @Ken. I know, just trying to justify my first comment. It turns out I was wrong. Arguments to a block are unpacked (unlike a function call), so the proposed in the answer is just fine.

Comment: @tokland, and if they weren't unpacked, then `*args` wouldn't really help with `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]`, though it might with `{1=>2,2=>3,4=>5}`

Answer (score 1):

I think the choice of implementation language depends on your application.

If you are network bound, Ruby should work fine. You might find it easier to implement concurrent requests using a [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) with [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki).  You can make HTTP requests using the [EventMachine::Protocols::HttpClient](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Protocols/HttpClient.html) class.

```
EventMachine.run {
   http = EventMachine::Protocols::HttpClient.request(
     :host => server,
     :port => 80,
     :request => "/index.xml"
   )
   http.callback {|response|
     # process response
   }
 }
```

This way you do not need to worry about concurrency and all of the associated complexity, but you will have high throughput since you can make a large number of concurrent requests.

If you are CPU bound this won't work.  If you are spending most of your time processing the XML feeds and not waiting on I/O to fetch the feed or insert into the database then you will have to run Ruby on JRuby or run multiple Ruby processes to achieve good multi-core utilization.

In the CPU bound case I would use Clojure, since if you are really CPU bound then doing the processing in Clojure will be easier to make parallel and just plain faster anyways.